# What spells affect Planeswalkers in MTG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does anyone know which spells can affect or Target Planeswalkers in MTG?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "affect"? After all, that could include anything from [Merciless Eviction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=420828), [Despise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386517) or even [Call the Gatewatch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407526). Maybe provide more info as to what kind of information you're actually looking for? As in, are you looking to handle your opponents' planeswalkers once they're on the battlefield, or are you wondering for different reasons altogether?

Answer (score 7):

There are a ton of such spells, in several categories. A spell might affect (or target):

- any permanent (e.g. [search for "target permament"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20[%22target%20permanent%22]))
- nonland permanents, noncreature permanents, etc (e.g. [search for "target nonland permanent"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20[%22target%20nonland%20permanent%22]))
- just planeswalkers, but this is rare (and there are things that say "target creature or planeswalker", so it's a little trickier to search for - [this works, but has false positives](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20[m/target.*planeswalker/]))

Along with those searches, you can also search for things like ["all nonland permanents"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20[%22all%20nonland%20permanents%22]) to find plenty of things that don't target.

And if a source you control deals non-combat damage to an opponent, you can redirect that damage to a planeswalker they control.

Comment: You can redirect any non-combat damage that would be dealt to an opponent to a planeswalker they control. The source doesn't have to be a spell.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I was stuck saying "spell" since the OP asked about spells, didn't mean to exclude other things.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of them. Here's a list of things to search for

- Things that **deal damage to players**; at resolution the controller of the spell/ability about to damage a player can redirect the damage to a planeswalker that player controls instead. There are way too many spells/abilities in magic that do this to list them all. If you do go looking, don't forget that the spell/ability doesn't need to target.
- **Creatures** can attack planeswalkers instead of players. Again, far too many to list.
- Anything that **targets planeswalkers**. Scratch that, actually; anything that has the word "planeswalker" in its rules text "affects" planeswalkers in some way.
- Anything that **targets permanents**, or otherwise affects them.

Needless to say, your question is incredibly broad.